# How do I add the values I have gotten through parse to get the "value" of the "column"?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, addition

My code goes through an input file and breaks it into "columns."

```
System.out.println(numberdouble);
```

It prints out the value for each row in that column. I tested this to check whether my program would properly iterate through the columns. I want to know how to output the sum of each column.

Example:

```
[a, 1, 2, 3]
[3, v, 3, x]
[5, 1, d, c]
```

If I sum the values at column 0, I want it to add 3 and 5 together. If a value in the column is not a number, it should convert the value to 0.

My code:

```
public static Double column_sum(String filename, int column)
{
    if(column < 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    File temp = new File(filename);
    Scanner input_file;
    try
    {
        input_file = new Scanner(temp);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    while(input_file.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = input_file.nextLine();
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")));
            Double numberdouble =0.0;
            String numberstring = myList.get(column);
            if(isDouble(numberstring))
            {
              numberdouble = Double.parseDouble(numberstring);
            }
            else
            {
              numberdouble=0.0;
            }
            System.out.println(numberdouble);
    }
    return 1.23; //placeholder
}
```

Comment: What would be the expect output in your example, while `column` is 0, 1, 2 and 3, respectively?

Comment: column : answer
0:8
1:2
2:5
3:3

Comment: Got it, please see my answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is create a 2 dimensional matrix. And store the values in that. After you do this it will be easy to parse and add a column.
As per you example:

```
Double [][] myMatrix = new Double[3][4];
int counter = 0, rowIndex=0,columnIndex=0;
while(input_file.hasNextLine())
{   counter++;
    if(counter%4 == 0)
    {
        rowIndex++;
        columnIndex=0;
    }
    String line = input_file.nextLine();
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")));
        Double numberdouble =0.0;
        String numberstring = myList.get(column);
        if(isDouble(numberstring))
        {
          numberdouble = Double.parseDouble(numberstring);
        }
        else
        {
          numberdouble=0.0;
        }
        myMatrix[rowIndex][columnIndex++] = number double;
        System.out.println(numberdouble);
}
```

Note: index's will chase this is strictly as per your example. You can make it more configurable.

Comment: is there a way to do it using what I have? I just want to know how to add the values, because the input file has many more columns and rows and I do not want to hardcode the amount of rows and columns into a matrix

Comment: Yes you could do it the way you want instead of 2D Array use a List<Double> this can grow dynamically. Keep string the total only the each column so the 0 element in the list is total 1st column son on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following code (I have tested it). Since I don't know the implementation of your `isDouble` function, I build a simple (but not elegant) one. I also remarked two unused lines, and added `input_file.close();` to close the resource. The content of "test.txt" is exactly the same as your input example:

```
a,1,2,3
3,v,3,x
5,1,d,c
```

Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ColumnSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(column_sum("test.txt", 0));
        System.out.println(column_sum("test.txt", 1));
        System.out.println(column_sum("test.txt", 2));
        System.out.println(column_sum("test.txt", 3));
    }

    public static boolean isDouble(String s) {
        try {
            Double.parseDouble(s);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static Double column_sum(String filename, int column) {
        Double sum = 0.0;
        if (column < 0) {
            return null;
        }
        File temp = new File(filename);
        Scanner input_file;
        try {
            input_file = new Scanner(temp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        // ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        while (input_file.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input_file.nextLine();
            List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")));
            Double numberdouble = 0.0;
            String numberstring = myList.get(column);
            if (isDouble(numberstring)) {
                numberdouble = Double.parseDouble(numberstring);
                sum += numberdouble;
            } else {
                numberdouble = 0.0;
            }
            // System.out.println(sum);
        }
        input_file.close();
        return sum;
    }
}
```

The output is (for each column):

```
8.0
2.0
5.0
3.0
```